# AC voltage for phase margin calculation

Tags: analog, phase-margin

When using Orcad PSpice to find the phase and gain margin of a circuit, like a linear power supply, what is the best voltage to use for the AC source? Its value affects the phase margin value. Most examples one finds on the net use 1 VAC, however, what if the output voltage is approaching 1 V, then the AC source is a significant percentage of that.

I was told by an "old timer" to use on the order of \$\frac{1}{10}\$ of Vout.
So I tried that with a 5 V supply and the phase margin with a 1 VAC source is 52° and with a 0.5 VAC source it's 84°.  Both are stable, but with a 30° delta, I can imagine that one could run into 20° (unstable?) and 50° (stable) with this scenario.

Which one would be correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9X701.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**UPDATE per @LvW and @Verbal Kint:**

Also followed this guide (which concurs with @LvW):
 [Two methods for SPICE-based amplifier stability analysis](https://www.planetanalog.com/two-methods-for-spice-based-amplifier-stability-analysis/)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxUhSo.png)</sup>

Comment: Please show a AC spectral plot of phase angle for both voltages. I ask this because I would want to examine the full spectrum. However, for a truly ideal linear circuit, it won't make any difference but, I suspect, LTspice might have "hit some problems" in your circuit.

Comment: Is it linear ?  The error correction must match the disturbance so there are limits on slew rate and amplitude. The schematic is unrealistic.

Comment: Ac analysis in SPICE implies *linear* circuits meaning that the ac source amplitude is irrelevant and won't saturate anything. It would of course be different in a transient analysis with a "real" sinusoidal source. Set your ac source to 1 V and it will do. Also, not sure what frequency you sweep, but 1T for CoL and LoL is quite huge to say the least, 1 kF and 1 kH usually work well enough. A small 100-mOhm in series with CoL has proven to be useful in some cases.

Comment: @Andyaka I wish I could, but IT prevents me from adding images.

Comment: @VerbalKint The sweep goes from 1Hz to 10MHz.  The 0 gain point is around 25kHz.  I tried using kilo instead of terra, but that created a phase margin of 412.  Weird, 412-360=52 which is what the PM is with the terra size parts.

Comment: @Andyaka Also, I'm not using LTSpice this time.  I'm using OrCad PSpice.  The vendor models are encrypted.  :(

Comment: @Aaron, hello, can you please post the OrCAD schematic with the dc bias points reflected on the schematic? This is important to verify that operating points are correct before considering the ac results, *always*.

Comment: @Aaron, you have broken the loop at a wrong place. The loop gain analysis will be not correct. This is because you have selected a node which is sensitive to the load (R3). In the case under discussion it is best to open the loop either directly at the opamp output (low output resistance) or at the inverting input (high input tesistance).

Comment: @LvW Thank you!  If you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it.  After making that change, the results didn't change with AC amplitude or using kilo vs terra sized parts.

Comment: @Aaron, which voltage ratio did you use for the loop gain?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to figure out phase/gain margins, that means you are linearizing the circuit and inherently try to aim for small-signal equivalents. If your simulation is an **AC** simulation, then the amplitude of the AC source will not matter for the phase or gain margin, but you should be careful to *divide the output amplitude by the input amplitude* to find the unity-gain frequency, don't use the amplitudes as-is.

If you are doing a **transient** simulation, then you are likely not able to assume that the circuit is linear, i.e. the circuit is a large-signal analysis and not a small-signal one. Gain and phase margins somewhat lose their meaning (your signal is not spectrally "pure", so you cannot use conventional circuit stability criterions).

Not really related to your core question, but I'm not sure whether the shown configuration is correctly configured for an open-loop analysis. For high frequencies, C2 and C3 are still closing the loop and might distort the results.

Comment: The selected node for breaking the loop is a bad one (see my comment to Aarons question).